# how to get value from hidden input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i have a any hidden input element. i want get value from a element. but tis code `$('#chin').val()` return `''`. hidden element for keep default value from the cotroller.

my code is:

```
<input placeholder="تاریخ ورود" class="datepicker" name="from" id="from" value="@Model.FromDate" />
<input ng-model="searchFilters.CheckInDate" name="chin" id="chin" hidden value="@Model.CheckInDate" />
```

and html is:

```
<input ng-model="searchFilters.CheckInDate" name="chin" id="chin" hidden="" value="2016/12/21" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
```

the input has value.
how to get value from this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need jQuery to get the value? Your model's `CheckInDate` value should have it.

Comment: In Model Set defaultValue. but i want get latest value

Comment: The just get the current value from the model. The current value is always there, just access `CheckInDate`.

Comment: i use this near datetimepicker. and i save defaultvalue from controler to this. and I do not change this

Comment: `<input placeholder="تاریخ ورود" class="datepicker pdp-el" name="from" id="from" value="1395/10/1" pdp-id="pdp-6201205">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete hidden input and Instead it use this code:

```
<input placeholder="تاریخ ورود"  class="datepicker" name="from" id="from" value="@Model.FromDate" data-gdate="@Model.CheckInDate" />
```

add `data-gdate="@Model.CheckInDate"` into end code.

Comment: get date with `var c = $("#from").attr('data-gdate')`

Answer (score 4):

You should be using Angular to retrieve that value. It will be in the model (`@Model.CheckInDate`).

Comment: i get value this code  `var c = $("#from").attr('data-gdate') || $("#chin").val();`

Comment: but retuen `''`

Comment: I think you just need to take a look at the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms As I mentioned before, you will not be able to get by using jQuery. jQuery should be avoided in Angular projects for the exact reason you're experiencing. Do not use jQuery